# Writing to File in Server-Side Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Web Applications at university, and at the moment we have an assignment: build a 'blog' using only CSS, Javascript and XML. We have to store the blog posts in a .xml file, which is what's got me stuck at the moment.

So, essentially I need to be able to write a Javascript function which writes to a server-side file. There are so many better ways to do this but we literally *have* to do it in Javascript. The teacher is totally unhelpful and everyone I asked thinks it can't be done.

I don't want anyone doing my work for me or anything, just it'd be nice to know how to do this, if it's even possible.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: I think that the teacher meant that you should READ the posts from xml files not save to XML. Because, AFAIK, it's not possible with JS to write to the file system.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what your blogging app should implement. Online editing and comments? This would be hard to do - but if you hold your postings in an rss-like xml file and ie create a timeline in Javascript on the client - thats perfectly doable. All that said: there are things like rhino or node.js that enable you to write servers in Javascript - but I doubt this to be the point of the assignment.

Comment: Makram: Actually, both.

flitzwald: I don't believe we have to worry about allowing posts to be edited, but we do have to allow other people to comment on them. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about JavaScript running in a browser, then you have to write some JavaScript that makes an HTTP request (possibly using XMLHttpRequest) to a server side process that will write the file. The client can't write directly to the server's filesystem.

If you are talking about JavaScript running on the server, then it depends on your JavaScript environment. There are lots of different ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript